# How does SetFit work for few shot text classification?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm seeking clarity on the utilization of SetFit for few-shot text classification, as discussed in the article [here](https://wandb.ai/gladiator/SetFit/reports/SetFit-Efficient-Few-Shot-Learning-Without-Prompts--VmlldzozMDUyMzk2). While I grasp the main concept, I'm having difficulty understanding the role of the evaluation dataset in SetFit Trainer.

To confirm my understanding: the initial training dataset is augmented by creating sentence pairs (positive or negative), and the augmented dataset is employed to fine-tune the sentence transformer. Subsequently, this fine-tuned transformer encodes the initial dataset (not the augmented one). The embeddings of the initial dataset are then used to train the classification layer, and the model's performance is assessed using a chosen metric.

However, I'm puzzled about the optional use of an evaluation dataset. If it is indeed optional, what purpose does it serve in this context?

thanks for the help !